# Get post data in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am new to wordpress coding.

I've problem to get `post_data` in wordpress , because I can't `var_dump` (using ajax process) so I can not see full data, but in inspect in Chrome  got parameter with this value

```
post_data: billing_first_name=&billing_last_name=&billing_country=ID&billing_address_1=&billing_address_2=&billing_city=&billing_state=&billing_city_ongkir=&billing_subdistrict_ongkir=
```

How can I get this **data per field** for example I want to get `billing_first_name`

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Come up with the code you have tried where we can be able to debug the problem and give you a solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the wordpress codex for help with wordpress coding issues.  Wordpress encodes the POST data so you should use the **stripslashes_deep** function to access post data if the data is encoded using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data .

```
$my_post = stripslashes_deep($_POST);
$my_value = $my_post['billing_first_name'];
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep

If you are posting the data using JSON you will need to use something more like this.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$my_post = json_decode($json);
$my_value = $my_post['billing_first_name'];
```